# I have two very similar functions but only one works

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, api-design

Why does the first function work and not the second one?  Both of the functions are within the same script statement. When I run the second function on my webpage it doesn't even get past the ajax statement but I am not sure what the actual problem is with it as I used the same template as the first function. Also please bear in mind I am very new to the Java API.

```
    function summonerLookUp() {
SUMMONER_NAME = $("#userName").val();

if (SUMMONER_NAME !== "") {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' + SUMMONER_NAME + '?api_key=RGAPI-F6099CCD-E674-478D-B9BF-2090B52A116C',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {

        },
        success: function (json) {
            SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES = SUMMONER_NAME.replace(" ", "");

            SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES = SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES.toLowerCase().trim();

            summonerLevel = json[SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES].summonerLevel;
            summonerID = json[SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES].id;


            document.getElementById("sLevel").innerHTML = summonerLevel;
            document.getElementById("sID").innerHTML = summonerID;

            sumName = json[SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES].name;
            sumID = json[SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES].id
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error getting Summoner data!");
        }
    });
} else {}
```

}

```
    function getMasteryData() {
SUMMONER_NAME = $("#userName").val();
sumID = string(sumID);


if (SUMMONER_NAME !== "") {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/championmastery/location/EUW1/player/' + sumID + '/champions?api_key=RGAPI-F6099CCD-E674-478D-B9BF-2090B52A116C',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {

        },
        success: function (json) {

            bestchampid = json[0].championId;
            document.getElementById("bcID").innerHTML = bestchampid;
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error getting Summoner data for the ID!");
        }
    });
} else {}
```

}

Sorry for bad formatting but I hope you can understand it.

Comment: you need to pass "sumID" in the second function. is this a global variable ?

Comment: Open your browser's web console. Observe the error there: `Uncaught ReferenceError: string is not defined` There is no built-in `string` fucntion in JavaScript. There is a `String` function, though it's unclear why you'd want it there, but it depends on what `sumID` is.

Comment: you can use toString() if you want to convert

Comment: sumID is a global variable in the code

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this line from the second function

`sumID = string(sumID);`

as there is no default function named string. Use `String()` instead.

Comment: Value is set in first function @ `sumID = json[SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES].id`

Comment: @SeinopSys: Read the answer again. void didn't say `sumID` wasn't set.

Comment: You're right. I wanted to point out that he should probably offer some alternate method to convert it to a string, but it indeed does not seem necessary.

Comment: @SeinopSys yea I know that the first function is setting the value, what I am saying is that the use of `string()` method is wrong as there is no JS method named `string()` instead you should use `String()`